# Copy current line or any particular line in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

How can we Copy current line or any particular line in Sublime Text?

Suppose that we have the file as shown below and we want to copy the whole current line that is line number 10 and also how can we copy the line number 5?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In simple terms:**

*Copying Current line*

> Press `Ctrl+c`

*Copying particular line*

> Step 1: Press `Ctrl+g`
>
> Step 2: Enter line number and Press `Enter`
>
> Step 3: Press `Ctrl+c`

**Detailed**

For copying the current line, just press `Ctrl+C`

If you want to copy any particular line number in the file , just say we want to copy line number 5 in the file as shown below

[image]

If you notice our current cursor is at line number 10, if we press `Ctrl+c` it copies whole current line (line number 10), provided there is no selection in the line and  for copying the line number 5 press `Ctrl+g` and type 5 (Line number you wish to go for) then press `Enter` this will take you to line number 5 and then press `Ctrl+c` which copies the line number 5 or any line which ever we wish for.

Comment: Great answer! For completeness I would also mention that this requires that the `copy_with_empty_selection` setting be turned on (it is by default, though).